# Assigning a value in SQLite cursor to a variable

Tags: android, sqlite

Iam trying to find average of a column in my sqlite database.
Here is the code:

```
public void getAvgMileage(Prediction pd) 
    {

    String [] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROW_ID, KEY_KM, KEY_FUEL_QTY, KEY_FUEL_PRICE, KEY_TOTAL_COST, KEY_MILEAGE, KEY_DATE,KEY_TANK_FULL};
    predictionCursor = ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT AVG(_mileage) FROM fuel_table WHERE _mileage IS NOT NULL ORDER BY _id DESC LIMIT 5", null);
                predictionCursor.moveToFirst();
                if(predictionCursor!=null && predictionCursor.getCount()>0)
                {
                    predictionCursor.moveToLast();
                   findAvgMileage = (Double.valueOf(predictionCursor.toString()));
                    pd.setpredictionMileage(findAvgMileage);
                }
}
```

But Iam geting a NullPointerException.
Any help??
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like you are getting the value out of the cursor for your SQL recordset

This line:

```
findAvgMileage = (Double.valueOf(predictionCursor.toString()));
```

looks like it's trying to take a double value of the tostring() of the actual cursor - which I don't think is going to usable or at least not parseable to Double. The return of Cursor.toString() may well be a null value.

replace the line with the following:

```
findAvgMileage = predictionCursor.getDouble(0);
```

This new line will fetch out the value in the first column of the current position of the curosr which in your SQL should be the average value you want.

Comment: YOu are right, I got rid of the null pointer exception but still get the wrong answer

Comment: Well it's a step in the right direction! Your SQL or the data itself will be the culprit of the wrong value. the avg() function will only  use non null values and it also equates anything that isn't a number (ie text or blobs) to zero which would throw off your average. try just "SELECT AVG(_mileage) from fuel_table" as your SQL and see if you get a different value.

Comment: Thank you for helping and also for the time you invested in explaining the concept. It shall definitely prove helpful for me in the future as well. I do think I have some problem with my data itself. I try to figure it out. Thanx a lot once again.